# Need help to make mail merge fully automated with python and without MS office installed

Tags: python, mailmerge, docxtpl

I am doing mail merge using docxtpl but to make it fully automated I have to make the context dynamic so I don't have to make change in code everytime for the different templates.

**Here is the code:**

```py
import pandas as pd
import os
from docxtpl import DocxTemplate

#Enter the complete filepath to the Word Template
#template_path = input("Insert the template file path : ")
template_path = os.getcwd() + "/sampledoc.docx"
print("Reading template from: " + template_path)

#For print variables
tpl = DocxTemplate(template_path)
variables = tpl.get_undeclared_template_variables()
print(f"\n Reading variables\n{variables}")

#Enter the complete filepath to the excel file which has the data
#source_path = input("Insert the source data file path : ")
source_path = os.getcwd() + "/source_data.xlsx"
print("\nReading source data from: " + source_path)
df = pd.read_excel(source_path)
print(f"\nPrinting source data\n{df}")

#Enter the complete filepath to the excel file where exported files will be saved
#save_dir = input("InserInsert the export directory path : ")
#os.chdir("export")
save_dir = "/storage/emulated/0/python/export/"

for variable in variables:
  locals()[variable] = df[variable].values
  
zipped = zip(Name,Age,Roll,Class,Score)
print("\nPerforming Mail Merge !")

for a,b,c,d,e in zipped:
  context = {"Name":a,"Age":b,"Roll":c,"Class":d,"Score":e}
  tpl.render(context)
  tpl.save(save_dir + '{}.docx'.format(a))
    
print("\nCongratulation! All files are exported to:\n"
       + str(save_dir[:-1]))
```

Want to change these bellow line dynamic so I don't have write the field name for different templates.

`zipped = zip(Name,Age,Roll,Class,Score`

`context = {"Name":a,"Age":b,"Roll":c,"Class":d,"Score":e}`

Comment: I don't see where you create variables `Name,Age,Roll,Class,Score` - but maybe you should use list instead separated variables.

Comment: maybe you should write separated functions for different templates and use `if/else` to select correct function. You could also use `sys.args` to select function using argument in command line - ie. `python script.py template1` and in code `if sys.args[1] == "template1": ....`

Comment: for variable in variables:
  locals()[variable] = df[variable].values
#for creating variable

Comment: I want to make a universal script which can merge any template by the provided excel data source.

Comment: universal code can be very complex problem.

Comment: using `locals()` is not preferred method. And it is better to use list `variables` or list `df[variable].values` instead separated variables Name,Age,Roll,Class,Score - it will be more universal - ie `for row in df[variable]:`

Comment: I can get the field variable from template and my source data has the same column header as variiable. So it is possible but I am learning python so don't know how to do it.

Comment: why not use `for index, row in df[variables].iterows():` instead of `zip()` - or something similar in `pandas`

Comment: this should be more universal `for index, row in df[variables].iterrows(): context = row.to_dict() ....`

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

If anyone need the code by help of @furas

**The code is:**

```py
for index, row in df[variables].iterrows():
    context = row.to_dict()
    tpl.render(context)
    tpl.save(save_dir + '{}.docx'.format(context["Name"]))
```

**The full code is also given bellow:**

```py
import pandas as pd
import os
from docxtpl import DocxTemplate

#Enter the complete filepath to the Word Template
#template_path = input("Insert the Word template file path : ")
template_path = os.getcwd() + "/sampledoc.docx"
print("\nReading template from: " + template_path)

#To print variables
tpl = DocxTemplate(template_path)
variables = list(tpl.get_undeclared_template_variables())
print(f"\nReading variables\n{variables}")

#Enter the complete filepath of the excel file which has the data
#source_path = input("Insert the source Excel data file path : ")
source_path = os.getcwd() + "/source_data.xlsx"
print("\nReading source data from: " + source_path)
df = pd.read_excel(source_path)
print(f"\nPrinting source data\n{df}")

#Enter the complete directory path where exported files to be saved
#save_dir = input("Insert the export directory path : ")
#save_dir = "/storage/emulated/0/python/export/"
os.chdir("export")
save_dir = os.getcwd() + "/"

for index, row in df[variables].iterrows():
    context = row.to_dict()
    tpl.render(context)
    tpl.save(save_dir + '{}.docx'.format(context["Name"]))
    
print("\nCongratulation! All files are exported to:\n" + save_dir)
```

Comment: you could first put only `for`-loop and later full code. This way it will be more visible what you changed in code